# How do I get this SQL SELECT COUNT statement to work how I think it should?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using SQL inside of Excel VBA for this. I am trying to get a count of [Diagrams] for distinct [Packets]. So, in the data table the [Packets] column will have duplicated packets. I need to count how many [Diagrams] exist for each packet.

Data Table:

```
| Diagrams | Packets  |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1526     |    525   |
| 1837     |    525   |
| 4-b-85   |    525   |
| a-468    |    503   |
| 3857     |    580   |
| b-d3d    |    580   |
| void     |    580   |
| c-854    |    503   |
| 0        |    525   |
```

Desired SQL Output:

```
| Packets  | Diagrams |
| -------- | -------- |
| 503      |      2   |
| 525      |      4   |
| 580      |      3   |
```

This is the sql statement that I'm currently trying to use that isn't working. It is giving me a syntax error, missing operator. It has something to do with the count part. When I take the "count diagrams" line out it runs how I would expect it to.

```
Sub CountOfDiagrams()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [Packets], [Diagrams]" & _
         "COUNT [Diagrams]" & _
         "FROM [MECHANICAL$]" & _
         "GROUP BY [Packets]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

' row
Dim r As Integer
r = 2
' column
Dim c As Integer
c = 1

Cells(r, c).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Eliminate the 2nd line of your strSQL and put [diagrams] inside a count() as diagrams text.. `strSQL = "SELECT [Packets], count([Diagrams]) as Diagrams" & _
         "FROM [MECHANICAL$]" & _
         "GROUP BY [Packets]"`

Comment: Thank you xQbert, this in addition to Hele's post helped me solve the problem. I did not realize count had to have the parenthesis and then the bracket.

Comment: SQL using an aggregrate function like "Count()"  must have all the non-aggregrates in the group by.  So eliminating diagrams without the count was the real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sql code looks fine, on a sqlite test db it works.

##### TEST TABLE

| id | diagrams | packets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1526 | 525 |
| 2 | 1837 | 525 |
| 3 | 4-b-85 | 525 |
| 4 | a-468 | 503 |
| 5 | 3857 | 580 |
| 6 | b-d3d | 580 |

##### TESTED SQL

```
SELECT packets, COUNT(packets) AS amount FROM test_table GROUP BY packets
```

| packets | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 503 | 1 |
| 525 | 3 |
| 580 | 2 |

Mhhhhm... never used vba in my life but as far as i can see **& _** allows multiline string concatenation, spaces are not required? Dunno, just a supposition. try to check your statement before the db call.

Hope it helps,
Hele

Comment: Yes, this helped me figure out the issue, thank you. I put your statement in as a single line and it ran as correctly. So, I stepped through mine to see what the statement looked like once it ran. The way it concatenated there were no spaces. Once I added a space before each " & _  it ran properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
     DISTINCT [Packets],
     COUNT(*)
FROM [MECHANICAL$]
GROUP BY [Packets]
```